# wooden floor seam staggering algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithms, f#

I will soon install wooden parquet floor in my home. And just for fun, I am thinking of writing an algorithm for making efficient use of the wooden planks I have.

Here's the problem:

- I have planks of different lengths enough to cover the surface.
- The room is rectangular (Later I would like to expand algorithm to take into account objects/walls in the room)
- Planks in adjacent rows should have their seams/joints staggered (atleast 20cm between adjacent joints)
  [How to stagger wood floor planks](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/stagger-wood-floor-planks-26159.html)
- Every new row should be started with the remainder of the cut-off of the previous row. I would prefer not to start new rows with a remainder smaller than 20cm
- The goal: I want the seams/joints pattern to look as random as possible and at the same time minimize cutting planks and have as little loss as possible of course.
- I am a .NET C# developer with some knowledge of F# and would like to use these to solve the problem.

My question is were do I start looking for inspiration on which base algorithms would fit my problem best?
Is this box stacking, bin stacking, linear stacking,...? Or better, has someone already solved this :-)?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306990/wooden-floor-seam-staggering-algorithm "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: Ok, what do I do then? Close my question on stackoverflow since someone voted to close, or close it here?

Comment: Pick one to keep and delete the other one.

Comment: The way you have specified the problem doesn't leave room for any optimization any more. You have already decided how to lay out the planks. I think you'll have to weaken some requirements. For example, allow starting a row using a piece left over from a different row than the previous one or putting cut pieces also in the middle of the room.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's still cross posted on stackoverflow

Comment: @5gon12eder: These requirements are fixed because cutting a piece means there is not tongue and groove joint on the cut, so that should always be the start or end of a row. That means that as soon as I do not use a cut-off piece for the next row, that piece (or the one I replace it with later) is lost, unless I can end a row with a full plank without having to cut.

Comment: The question on stackoverflow is now closed. I would delete it, but then I get a message saying that deleting posts with an answer is not recommended.

Comment: You know what would make these easier? The fact that when you have repeating parallel lines (hardwood, square tile or linoleum) it generally looks better offset 45 degrees. Well, maybe that is not easier.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a very general algorithm useful for these types of problems. This algorithm is mainly useful for your specific problem because you have a relatively small search space. If your search space was huge, you would need some complex optimizations.

Select a fixed number of random choices for the next plank to be laid down. For all those choices, make another set of random choices, etc. This is similar to a chess algorithm. At some point, you will be concerned about memory or CPU usage, since your tree is expanding. You can perform a search to a certain depth, then select the best branch among those, then continue the tree search from there.